# Which Firefox version is compatible with Selenium 2.48.0

Tags: firefox, selenium, selenium-firefoxdriver

who can help me?

Which Firefox version is compatible with Selenium 2.48.0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Selenium WebDriver 2.48 supports till firefox version 41.0 , For more details please have a look at changelog of selenium webdriver.

[**Selenium ChangeLOG**](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/CHANGELOG)

Comment: I don't see anywhere in the changelog that specifically states which versions of selenium webdriver are compatible with which versions of Firefox. Would you mind pointing out to me where I should be looking?

Answer (score 5):

Selenium support for Firefox is the latest release, the previous release, the latest ESR release and the previous ESR release.

**Selenium 2.48.0** is supported for **Firefox from 24 to 41**, unless I'm missing something.

I know I have used **Selenium 2.47 with Firefox 41**. Are you having specific issues with it?