# C# Selenium: Create FireFoxProfile with LAN path

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I create a profile with parameter is Profile Directory

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile(path);
driver = new OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriver(profile);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

path is a LAN path: @"\\192.168.1.1\Profiles\profile1"

It worked but randomly, I tested on 2 VPS, once ran app, once (192.168.1.1) containts Profiles, both runs WIN XP.

But when I put app and Profiles to other server with 2 other VPS, app was freezed at FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile(path);

Can body have any idea, please?

Comment: are you able to start that profile in problematic VPS manually?

Comment: Yes, I can start by choice profile after run firefox -p.
I'm wondering if my problem is Selenium and FF version? my Selenium is 2.48, FF on VPS that worked is 36.0.1 and FF on server (not worked) is 43.0.1

Comment: yes, you are correct. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33030954/which-firefox-version-is-compatible-with-selenium-2-48-0

Comment: Yeah, you save my day, murali. I will check this problem.